# ItemizedOverlay class in Android

Tags: android

I was going through an example using ItemizedOverlay. The draw method is being over-ridden as follows:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    shadow = false;
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}
```

In the example, a call is being made to populate(), which in turn calls size() and createItem(int i).

But my question is, who calls the above-mentioned draw method, and how is it called? In particular, how does the caller know which MapView object to pass as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

> who calls the above-mentioned draw method, and how is it called?

`invalidate()` method force the view to draw which is implemented in the View class, invalidate is called by you or by the system whenever you require to draw your view.

When you Create a private inner class which extends Overlay which override the `draw method` with  couple of parameters.

- The first argument is a handle to an instance of Canvas which we will
  use to draw our marker on.
- The second is an instance of MapView on which this overlay is displayed.
- The third argument is a boolean which indicates whether we are drawing the actual image, or the shadow.

In fact, this method is called twice. Once to draw the shadow and once to draw the actual thing you want to draw.

Below are couple of links which help you

[How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)

[Drawing multiple location markers on a MapView](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=509EB1AD88ECB395598B6F1F5DC8361D?recipeId=2308)

[Class Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay)